# what does the value 1 Indicate in Mongo DB Collection Field Index?

Tags: mongodb

I am using Mongo DB for our Application .

To OPtimize the Application first ,  we started initailly on Indexing Mongo DB COllections .

I have seen a example in net shown below  as how to do a Indexing On a collection

```
db.products.ensureIndex( { "category": 1, "item": 1 } )
```

Please let me know what does the value 1 Indicate here ?? Is that standard ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It represents the order of the keys in the index. 1 for an ascending order and -1 for a descending. More details in  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/